# How to parse a list of list of floats in python?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am fairly new to python and I got a C program which can output a list of floats like this one :

```
f11
f12
...
f1n

f21
f22
...
f2m

.
.
.
fk1
...
fkl
```

I would like to get these floats into a list of list :

```
[[f11,...], [f21, ...], ..., [fk1,...]]
```

I have a solution (using a specific float as a delimiter) but it is quite ugly. The format of the input is flexible...Is there a simple solution ?

Comment: Are the ellipses and dots in the input actually what you're getting in, or are you including them as a placeholder? Is there always two newlines between each "set" of floating point numbers?

Comment: This is a placeholder (though I'm not sure of what it means) : it's a long list of floats so I just indicate the list goes on with "...". As I said, I can output the data as I want. I put a blank line but it could be something else.

Comment: he's asking how we should know what delimits one sub-list of floats from the next.  Is there a blank line in between them, or...

Comment: It seems I wasn't clear...but anyway I got a solution...I will probably delete the question and get some sleep. Thanks for your interest. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your numbers look something like this:

```
1.435235
3.23421
4.523421
42.3241

-1.2342
0.09901
134134.2

1.2342111
13.111
14.23521
```

...where each group of numbers is separated by two newlines, you could have something like this:

```
def parse_group(group):
    return [float(n) for n in group.split('\n')]

def get_numbers(string, separator='\n\n'):
    groups = str.split(separator)
    return [parse_group(group) for group in groups]
```

Calling `get_numbers` on your function should yield something like:

```
>>> print get_numbers(input)
[[1.435235, 3.23421, 4.523421, 42.3241], [-1.2342, 0.09901, 134134.2], [1.2342111, 13.111, 14.23521]]
```

This assumes that each group is separated by two newline characters (a blank line), but you could parametrize it accordingly.